# How to programatically detach drop down list from Android Spinner

Tags: android

I created a Spinner in Android 4.2 and programatically popualted drop down list that comes on click on spinner. I made the spinner to be clicked automatically using the method "performClick()" which opens up drop down list. Now is there a way in which I can cancel the drop down list of the spinner programatically.can any one help me in sorting out this issue.

Comment: But no proper answer found there

Comment: If you want to get more visibility on a question, you can do things like offer a bounty... You shouldn't ever double-post.